# Issue with MS Word Hyperlink to a heading

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, hyperlink, table-of-contents

I customized the headings in a Word template that I use for writing all of my instruction documents.  I wrote a document recently and used hyperlinks to help the reader jump to different sections of the document.  All of my hyperlinks work great except for 2 of them.  I set the headings for 2 sections to "Heading 4".  The text of these headings are "Option One" and "Option Two".
The text of the the hyperlinks are also "Option One" and "Option Two".  (Somewhat obviously, I want the hyperlink on "Option One" to redirect the user to the section with heading "Option One".)

However, no matter what I do, the hyperlinks always change to the following syntax: "#*Option*#1:_1" and "#*Option*#2:_2".  When you click on the hyperlinks you are redirected to the Table of Contents at the beginning of my document.

I can't figure out why this is happening or why it's happening to only those two links.  Any ideas?
(P.S. this would be much easier to explain if I was able to post screenshots, but apparently I need "10 reputation" for that.)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (but I'm on Word 2010). How are you creating the link? As a link to a `place in this document`? If you press `alt-F9` over the link, exactly what does it show?